# Create Photo Gallery for online image in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gallery, android-gallery, photo-gallery

I have a set of about 100 urls which are images. Like http://www.site1.com/Image/img1.jpg and http://www.site2.com/Image/phot1.jpg.

I want to have a android application to show all the images in full screen and support swipe left and right just like the default image gallery in android. The difference is that the image would load from a url and not from SD card.

I also need to take care of bandwidth usage where i do not want to load all images at once. Only load say the first 3 images and then once the user is on the 3rd image load the 4th in the back end. This is to make the load faster and also to conserve bandwidth.

Is there any such gallery implementation sample in android which i can start of with. Please help me in this regards. I would appreciate any kind of advice in this regards. My intention is to load online images into a android application as a native photo app. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, have a look on this website:
http://www.anddev.org/gallery_with_remote_images-t769.html

You can easily use Gallery widget, you adjust the layout to make it full screen. It reuse views so you wont use too much data only what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you asked to implement full application.. rather you should come up with specific questions.. like you did something and you face some error..

Anyways, there are many frameworks/libraries/utilities out there which can perform your work.. i dont think, a single library/utility will perform all what u need.

So to load image from url, you can use Droid-Fu

For swiping left and right and keeping memory in mind, you can use view pager and fragments.

Go through the examples of each and then combine them to make your application.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The source code, or at least most of it, to the official gallery application is part of the Android Open Source Project. You can find instructions for accessing the git repository(-ies) at  https://android.googlesource.com/. You'll need to scroll way down, to platform/packages/apps/Gallery (and Gallery3d and Gallery2).

At some point, you'll need to learn how to manage concurrency yourself, for example, by [creating a fixed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29).